# Bluetooth Low Energy pairing using NFC [Nokia TreasureTag]

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc, bluetooth-lowenergy, nokia

Nokia Treasure tag (http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/mobile/accessory/ws-2/) is a small device which you can pair with your device and then attach with keychains and other things.

It works on the Bluetooth Low Energy communication. But unlike the traditional method where you scan for the devices, it pairs with the NFC.

I was wondering how it's done?

What I want to do is, pair with the treasure tag and white on it's GATT service characteristics and establish a connection and when I press the button on the treasure tag, I get a notification on my phone.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.